# Publish Option in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2012, publish

When I right-click on a website to publish it, on clicking the Publish option from the menu that appears, I don't see full options.

Like, on clicking the '**Publish**' tab, I don't see the normal window that we see. Instead I just see few lines that say '**Publishing to Windows Azure?**', '**Select or import a public profile**'.

I searched it online but they only talk about deploying and not the initial setup. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to setup a publish profile before doing anything else. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @mac, thank you for that link. It solved my problem.